# Do Greeks need a passport to visit Turkey?

Tags: international-travel, eu, turkey, greece, greek-citizens

I have a Greek ID. Can I fly to Instabul (Constantinople) from Athens with just my ID, do I need a passport?

This [guide](https://www.worldtravelguide.net/guides/europe/turkey/passport-visa/#:%7E:text=Nationals%20of%20the%20following%20countries,%2C%20Portugal%2C%20Spain%20and%20Switzerland) states that:

> Nationals of the following countries can **travel to Turkey** as tourists or as business travellers with a valid **identity card** or a valid passport: [...], **Greece**, ...

Is this true? Can anyone confirm or provide an official website source?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Turkish MFA site confirms](https://www.mfa.gov.tr/countries-whose-citizens-are-allowed-to-enter-T%C3%BCrkiye-with-their-national-id_s.en.mfa):

> **Countries whose citizens are allowed to enter Türkiye with their national ID’s**
>
> ...
>
> 15. Greece
>
> ...

Comment: Ministry of Foreign Affairs seems pretty official :)

Comment: Strangely "Multi-Factor Authentication" works here too...

Comment: Unfortunately this applies only for new type of IDs, rather uncommon from my experience in Greece; see my answer.

Answer (score 4):

> Do Greeks need a passport to visit Turkey?

Not necessarily.

I asked Greeks that flew to Constantinople and they told me that if your ID is older than 15 years, you may experience delays, or even problems (at worst).

Indeed the [Greek MFA](https://www.mfa.gr/turkey/ypiresies/loipes-uperesies/proxenike-odegia-skhetika-me-te-diarkeia-iskhuos-diabaterion-kai-taxidiotikon-eggraphon-ellenon-politon-pou-episkeptontai-ten-tourkia.html#:%7E:text=%CE%91%CF%80%CF%8C%20%CF%84%CE%B7%CE%BD%201%CE%B7%20%CE%99%CE%B1%CE%BD%CE%BF%CF%85%CE%B1%CF%81%CE%AF%CE%BF%CF%85%202015,%CE%B5%CF%80%CE%B9%CF%80%CE%BB%CE%AD%CE%BF%CE%BD%20%CE%B1%CF%80%CE%B1%CE%B9%CF%84%CE%BF%CF%8D%CE%BC%CE%B5%CE%BD%CE%B7%20%CE%B4%CE%B9%CE%AC%CF%81%CE%BA%CE%B5%CE%B9%CE%B1%20%CE%B9%CF%83%CF%87%CF%8D%CE%BF%CF%82%20%CE%B4%CE%B9%CE%B1%CE%B2%CE%B1%CF%84%CE%B7%CF%81%CE%AF%CE%BF%CF%85) mentions:

> οι Έλληνες πολίτες μπορούν να εισέρχονται στην Τουρκία με **νέου τύπου αστυνομική ταυτότητα**
>
> > Greek citizens can enter Turkey with a new type of police identity card

In Greece it's very common to have old type IDs, mine is 17 years old because I had to get my Cambridge English diploma (rather typical for Greek students).

Comment: Why is the diploma relevant to what type of ID you have?

Comment: Because you need to have an ID to give the exams, which was what triggered issuing the ID for most of the kids back in my school days @JonathanReez-onstrike. I believe the Greek citizens reading my answer in the future will relate.